# In Matlab, how do I create a CSV file from a subset of the lines in a text file?

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv

I need to open a text file and convert it into a CSV file in Matlab. The first 3 lines of the text file are sentences that need to be omitted. The next 28 lines are numbers that need to make up the first column of the CSV, and then the next 28 lines need to make up the second column.

The text file is called `datanal.txt` and the output file can be named anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention I've almost completely forgot matlab syntax, so I need a laid out code that I can just copy paste in matlab. Sorry for being bad guys :\

Comment: ...or you could take 30 seconds and look it up... http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/

Comment: Any reason why you're using MATLAB to do that? The task seems more suited to a scripting language, with friendlier string manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

Don't have Matlab now to test, but try this. Your input file should be in Matlab's current directory, or put the full path to the file name.

```
A = csvread('datanal.txt',3,0);
A = reshape(A,28,2);
csvwrite('output.csv',A)
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can add #'s in front of the first 3 lines then use load and a reshape. Did you need a fully automated script or is there only one file? If you're familiar with matlab at all there are a bunch of ways to turn that large column vector into a matrix.